# how to include new font and use it in project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
@font-face {
      font-family: Sakal Marathi , Arial Unicode MS;
      src: url(Saka_Marathi_Normal.ttf);
    }
    
 h3{
 font-family: Sakal Marathi , Arial Unicode MS;
 }
```

```html
<h3>hiiii</h3>
```

I am desiging my project using bootstrap, vuejs, and laravel. I want to add the font sakal_marathi.ttf to my project. How can I use this font style? When I use the font-family attribute it displays the font on my PC, but the effect is not displayed on other computer.

Comment: Your Browser might use an installed font on your machine. Open the developer toolbar (F12) and check if the font has been loaded!

Comment: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

upload your fonts here and get css and fonts from their hope it is useful you need to add all fonts like (woff2, woff, eot etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use any [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) instead this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Sakal Marathi';
  src: url('Saka_Marathi_Normal.ttf');
}

h13 {
  font-family: "Sakal Marathi";
}
```

You don't have to use two names(the first is font series name,the second is font type name),and you should check current url is true.